# How do I make Bamboo understand phpspec tests?

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo, phpspec

Bamboo gives us the ability to run phpunit tests, but likely given a lower popularity, nothing for phpspec.

I suspect however (Googling) that it must be possible!
https://revive.beccati.com/bamboo/browse/PHP-PHPSPEC-813/test

Has anyone successfully fed phpspec tests into Bamboo?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to run the test with the junit formatter.  Bamboo has built-in support for the former, and this made the tests run smoothly.

Comment: OK. I did consider this approach, but phpspec's junit output was just a single line of PHP error. Have you tested a failure case?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to run the phpspec test as a Script Task. If the task returns a non-0 exit code, the build fails. phpspec obligingly returns a 0 exit code only when all your tests pass.

In order to do this you would need to ensure that phpspec is available to your Bamboo build. If you're using Composer, you can add it to the `require-dev` section of your `composer.json` file.

Then, in the Plan Configuration, under Default Job (or some other job), you can add a new task of type Script. This Script Task can then make a call to phpspec:

```
vendor/bin/phpspec run 1>&2
```

You may also want (as above) to redirect the output to stderr because Bamboo seems to suppress any output on stdout. This will then allow you to see the output of phpspec in your Bamboo log.